# Firebase Phone Authentication: Is it possible to only check if the telephone exists in Authentication and not Sign Up the user automatically?

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Phone Auth and Javascript.

When a user logs in on my app if the Phone Number doesn't exist in firebase a new user is created in Authentication with the phone provided. Is it possible to have some users predefined and not let new users to create an account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn off user signups. However, you can deploy a cloud function to automatically delete new users instantly upon registration:

```
exports.deleteNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((userRecord, context) => {
  const uid = userRecord.uid; // The Firebase user.
  admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Successfully deleted user: " + uid);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
    });
});
```

Anyway, if you're using the login call on the front-end instead of the signup call, a new user shouldn't be created anyway.